# Visual basic - Check if ActiveWorkbook.Save() was successful

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, excel-2010, worksheet

How can i check, if this saving command was successful?

```
Dim objExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
End Sub
```

For example, while the program is working in a remote excel workbook, and the connection goes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a workaround.
Before update, the last Excel row number is stored, then after update, i store that number too.

```
objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\filename.xlsx")
objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lRow = objSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Row + 1
beforeUpdate = lRow

'updating happens
objSheet.Cells(lRow, 1).value = TextBox1.Text

'finding the last available row again
lRow = objSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Row + 1
afterUpdate = lRow

If beforeUpdate < afterUpdate Then
  MessageBox.Show("Successful update.")
Else
  MessageBox.Show("The update was unsuccessful!")
End If
```

This workaround makes it for me.